# Css selector is not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am having problem in calling html elements from CSS, via CSS selectors. Strangely, the class selectors are working, but i can not select the elements from CSS. So i had to give them classes.

What i want to do is; When the Mouse hovers on  i want `<ul>` to appear, and when Mouse does not hovers `<a>,` I want `<ul>` (menu) to dissapear.

Html:

```
<div id="cFilter">
           <a href="#" class="menus">Sort by date</a>
           <ul class="uls">
               <li class="lis">From old to new</li>
               <li class="lis">From new to old</li>
           </ul>

</div>
```

Css:

```
.menus {
    color:#2a2d4d;
    float:left;
    margin-left:13px;
    margin-top:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#ffd800;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    position:relative; 
    z-index:9999;

}
    .menus:hover > ul{
   color:#4d78bd;
   cursor:pointer;
   display:block;
         }
.uls {
   display:none; 
    background-color:#808080;
    width:150px;
    height:60px;
    margin-top:60px;
    list-style-type:none;float:left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 14px;
    margin-bottom:-100px;
}
.lis:hover {
color:#eedede;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Here is my fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdLjkt64/)

Hope someone can help me..

Comment: fiddle link not working

Comment: Please post your code in your question, don't expect us to traipse around the internet in order to help you.

Comment: @punithasubramaniv its working

Comment: I am sorry but i just thought that people would ask me for fiddle and thought would be easier like that. I have no intention to traipse anyone.. @DavidThomas

Comment: People would inevitably ask for a JS Fiddle demo, but that's not a requirement (though it's very useful); the relevant code, however, is if the problem is with the code itself.

Comment: I am new here. Thanks, I will keep in mind. @DavidThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using the wrong selector:

```
.menus:hover > ul {
```

The `>` is a direct child selector. And your `ul` is not a child of your `a.menus`. They are sibilings, so you would have to use `+` for imediate sibilings, or `~` for general sibilings:

```
.menus:hover ~ ul {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rdLjkt64/2/

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 .menus:hover ~.uls
 {
 color:#4d78bd;
 cursor:pointer;
 display:block;
 }
```

If you want to use Element selector instead

```
.menus:hover ~ ul
{
color:#4d78bd;
cursor:pointer;
display:block;
}
```

**`>`** is a direct child selector, so it wont wok as **ul** is not a child

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdLjkt64/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this

```
.menus:hover + .uls
{
   color:#4d78bd;
   cursor:pointer;
   display:block;
}
```

**OR**

```
.menus:hover + ul
{
   color:#4d78bd;
   cursor:pointer;
   display:block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/rdLjkt64/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add plus

```
.menus:hover > .uls
```

to

```
.menus:hover + .uls
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to display the next element (<ul>) on hovering the previous one (<a>). To achieve this use the "+" selector to affect the next sibling:

```
    .menus:hover + ul
```

instead of the child selector (>) you have been using before.

```
    .menus:hover > ul
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdLjkt64/4/)

But this causes the  to hide again if you enter it by mouse, so replace the hovered Element with its parent and use the child selector again:

```
    #cFilter:hover > ul
```

like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdLjkt64/5/)